# Windows Store Apps- GridView Item width

Tags: gridview, windows-store-apps

I am trying to create a GridView with different width for each of its Items. I've declared all the items in my XAML ( i.e.they are predefined) and have given them different width sizes. But when the application runs all the items get equal width. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post a small sample of your xaml?

Answer (score 1):

GridView uses VariableSizedWrapGrid panel to layout its children elements. There seem to be a bug that makes all items in the grid to be of same size as the first item. Check this thread on MSDN forums for details: [VariableSizedWrapGrid / WrapGrid Strange Measuring](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/winappswithcsharp/thread/569e048a-9f5e-4fb3-870a-380de5906e80)

You will need to replace that panel with the one that actually supports variable sized elements.

Example:

```xaml
     <GridView>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        ...
     </GridView>
```